# Set labels in matplotlib legend columns

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating a plot with three datasets. Two of the datasets has three columns, the third has four columns. I would like a legend with the first column containing the labels for the first dataset, the second column containing labels for the second dataset, and the third column containing the four labels from the third dataset. Using only `ncols=3` in the call to legend produces this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

num_time_points = 10
time_values = pd.date_range(start='2023-01-01', periods=num_time_points, freq='H')

analytical_data = np.random.rand(num_time_points, 3) * 100  # 3 columns
analytical_df = pd.DataFrame(analytical_data, columns=['t_A', 't_B', 't_C'], index=time_values)

model_data = np.random.rand(num_time_points, 3) * 100  # 3 columns
model_df = pd.DataFrame(model_data, columns=['m_A', 'm_B', 'm_C'], index=time_values)

stiff_model_data = np.random.rand(num_time_points, 4) * 100  # 4 columns
stiff_model_df = pd.DataFrame(stiff_model_data, columns=['sm_C', 'sm_B', 'sm_A2', 'sm_A1'], index=time_values)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=300)

analytical_df.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.5)
model_df.plot(ax=ax, ls='--')
stiff_model_df.plot(ax=ax, ls='dotted')

ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.legend(ncol=3)
```

[image: incorrect legend]

I can, however, make the entire legend myself like this, but I'm not sure if the axes lines are guaranteed to always be in the same order:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=300)

analytical_df.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.5)
model_df.plot(ax=ax, ls='--')
stiff_model_df.plot(ax=ax, ls='dotted')

custom_lines = [
    # col 1
    ax.lines[0],
    ax.lines[1],
    ax.lines[2],
    Line2D([0], [0], color='white', lw=0),
    # col 2
    ax.lines[3],
    ax.lines[4],
    ax.lines[5],
    Line2D([0], [0], color='white', lw=0),
    # col 3
    ax.lines[6],
    ax.lines[7],
    ax.lines[8],
    ax.lines[9]
]

ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.legend(custom_lines, 
    analytical_df.columns.tolist() + [''] +
    model_df.columns.tolist() + [''] +
    stiff_model_df.columns.tolist(), ncols=3
)
```

[image: corrected legend]

Is there a way to guarantee that lines and labels are correct?